# Why does JFrame paint graphics three times and not one?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, window

I made a simple program that paints a blue background and turns red after repainting 10 times and i noticed that whenever i run the program it paints the window three times at start and not one? Does anyone know why it does this?

My MainClass:

```
package jframe_color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class mainClass extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PaintWindow SetPaint = new PaintWindow()
```

And this is my PaintWindow class:

```
package jframe_color;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class PaintWindow extends JFrame {

int count = 0;
public PaintWindow(){
    setSize(400,400);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    if (count < 10)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        count += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }
    g.fillRect(0,  0,  this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("count is " + count, 100, 100);
```

Comment: The paint methods will be drawn as and when the JVM thinks it might be necessary.  This might include things like bringing a window in front of, then removing it from the app., minimizing then restoring it, moving or resizing the container..  So whatever you do, code so those repaints are expected at ..any time.

Comment: Other tips: 1) `g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));` would better be `g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 18));` for both compile time checking and X-platform support. 2) Never paint in a top level container like `JFrame`.  Instead paint in a `JPanel` and add that panel to the top level window.  There are a number of good reasons for this, that are too long to express in a comment.

Comment: As @AndrewThompson states, and 3) Because you can never control when or even if painting will occur, never put program logic within a painting method. By logic, I mean anything that changes the state of your view such as the change in the count variable. Instead, increment your count elsewhere, perhaps in a Timer, or in response to some event, then call `repaint()` and have your JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` use the count variable result to help it decide what to draw (but again, paintComponent should not change the count value).